# how to efficiently get average cpu usage of remote linux machine?

Tags: c#, linux, ssh, cpu-usage

How to get average CPU usage of remote Linux machine in particular day using ssh in c#?
I have used Sharpssh package for getting cpu usage at any particular moment but how to get average when i will ping to that machine?

Comment: use the command `top` to get the CPU usage at that particular point. You can also take logs from the use of tools like TERATERM by writing it to a file.

Comment: Have a look here http://superuser.com/questions/49814/average-load-and-total-cpu-in-top.

Answer (score 2):

You should parse `/proc/loadavg` , you will see something similar to this

```
[~]> cat /proc/loadavg
0.02 0.02 0.05 1/125 1525
```

`First column` : CPU/IO load for the last minute

`Second column` : CPU/IO load for the last 5 minutes

`Third column`  : CPU/IO load for the last 10 minutes

`Fourth column` : Active process count / Total process count

`Fifth column`  : Last proces ID (PID) used

You can decide depending on first four columns.

Comment: Is load average is for cpu load or processes in queue requesting cpu?

Answer (score 1):

not getting your requirement but using  `top` command you can know the CPU usage.

Comment: there are large number of machines so i have to get average CPU usage of each and every machine(every day) in order to know the workload on each and every machine